# Where is the php7.4-fpm.sock located if I we use the image php:7.4-fpm?

Tags: php, nginx, php-7.4

Hi I pulled the image of php:7.4-fpm

```
FROM  php:7.4-fpm
```

after the containers is up when I exec the the service and cd on this

```
root@05a7991437c0:/var/run/php#
```

but it is empty

I tried to exec the container and `service php7.4-fpm status`

it says `php7.4-fpm: unrecognized service`

I want to change my nginx.conf to fpm.sock

```
fastcgi_pass php:9000;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Docker containers are usually build as one process per container. Therefore a scheduler is not added. service won't work in most containers. _"Where is the php7.4-fpm.sock located if I we use the image php:7.4-fpm?"_ Why do you expect a "php7.4-fpm.sock"? Can you check fpm config for `listen`? There you can change it from network socket to file socket.

Comment: You can find it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php)

Answer (score 0):

I needed same for creating virtual host for local nginx..
Below worked for me :

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```

Make sure u remove the file `your_local_domain` from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` before recreating a soft link like below :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_local_domain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```